# How to use the twitter API using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, api, twitter

I am new to using API's and have so far successfully implemented the Google Maps API which was just obtaining the API key and some correctly placed code. I am now trying to use the twitter API but the documentation almost makes no sense. Can anyone guide me in the right direction or post a simple guide on how it works. I dont want to post any tweets, I simply want to make a twitter feed on a webpage where users can enter a word and the twitter feed then displays all recent tweets containing that word.

The twitter widget isn't dynamic enough for this purpose so the API seems like the correct route to use.

Comment: http://google.it? *how to use twitter api in js* returns many results...

Comment: I have but the results are about setting up a twitter widget(which I have stated, cannot be used dynamically). @Jonasw

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you know NODE JS but if you do then you can use a module called "Twit". Really easy documentation is here: https://github.com/ttezel/twit

Comment: absolute legend @JohnsonsGaming. Works like a charm.